# Is there a good Animation to explain Rotational Symmetry of Equilateral triangle

Tags: secondary-education, geometry, applications

I am willing to teach that the Order of rotational Symmetry of Equilateral triangle as $3$ using Animation. Any suggestions of good applet which demonstrates the rotation of equilateral triangle with different angles like $30^{\circ},60^{\circ},$ etc about the centre?

Comment: If you want, you can easily produce a Desmos diagram showing these rotations (there are ways to animate things in Desmos, and make buttons with prescribed actions).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple, dynamic presentation: [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Npo0LgkklUQ&ab_channel=SimplyAnimatedMath)---only 2 minutes,
from "Simply Animated Math":

[image]

For more explanation (and less animation),
this may be *too* detailed, but you could select just the portion on the
equilateral triangle: [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZGcIIEwW1Xs&ab_channel=PocketClassroom) (11min total, equilateral triangle: 6min).

[image]

Comment: (+1) But when something looks wrong (2nd fig.) and then, thinking on it, is wrong, I can't help but being distracted by it. At first, I thought it was an optical illusion brought on by the grid, but then I noticed: Doesn't it bother you that all the vertices and centroid lie on what is apparently a square grid?

Comment: @Raciquel: Sharp eyes! I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in the comment, things like this are achievable with Desmos. Let me describe a proof of concept here. You can [look it up](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/eynemdpv4j), but please beware that I'm no programmer and no Desmos expert.

If you define a point $A=(1,0)$ and a function $R(P,\alpha)$ that returns the point $P$ rotated by $\alpha$ around $0$, then typing the following *action*
$$
A \to R \left( A,\frac{2\pi}{3} \right)
$$
(typed with `->`) will produce a button which rotates $A$ by $\frac{2\pi}{3}$. You could make it into an animation by defining
$$
B = R(A, \alpha)
$$
and adding a parameter $\alpha$. Desmos lets you bound $\alpha$ to the interval $\left[0, \frac{2\pi}{3}\right]$ and animate its changes.

Another method of animating it (I'm not sure if it's better in any way) is to  use a *ticker* that says `Run A -> R(A,0.01*dt) every 20 ms`. Then the point $A$ will get rotated a bit every 20 ms (`dt` is the time step, so changing `20 ms` to something else won't alter the pace of animation). The problem with this approach is that the rotation doesn't stop after reaching the desired point. In the [example](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/eynemdpv4j) I gave, I used a cheap get-around: the animation slows down when it reaches its final point.